# Getting 400 Bad request error when sending huge amont of data with post

Tags: ajax, struts2, tomcat6

I am using yahoo YUI Ajax call to post request.

Page is developed in JSP and server is Tomcat 6 and using Struts 2.x.

While i am sending small amount of data using Ajax call post request it is working fine.But when i am sending huge amount of data i am getting 400 bad request error.

Comment: Please make sure you are sending a post request. For instance if you re using Jquery depending on its version you may be confused between type or method to specify HTTP method. Please look at this thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543174/what-is-the-diff-between-type-and-method-in-ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Please check maxPostSize attribute of Connector in conf/server.xml.

[See the following doc for the details](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html)

Answer (score 0):

The 400 error comes when The Web server thinks that the data stream sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser ) was 'malformed' i.e. did not respect the HTTP protocol completely. So the Web server was unable to understand the request and process it.

There could be possibilities that data is too large, so you should better encode the data using java script inbuilt function for example escape().

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat, when the post data exceeds the maximum specified in maxPostSize (server.xml) it returns a 400 as error code