# What is the Diff between type and method in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, methods

HI i have used both the things in my experience 
i was thinking method and type both are **POST** and **GET** methods.

> But seems like they are not similar.?

if i use `type` it is working i am `serializeing` a form data..

if i write `method` it is not working can can anyone explain what is the diff between them..?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "controller.php",
  type: 'POST',
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
});
```

help is appropriated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

type (default: 'GET')
Type: String
An alias for method. You should use **type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.**

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 22):

From: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**method**:

```
The HTTP method to use for the request (e.g. "POST", "GET", "PUT"). (version added: 1.9.0)
```

**type**:

```
An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.
```

Answer (score 6):

both are same, in new version of jQuery type renamed to method

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, there doesn't seem to be any issue with the usage of the method property in the `$.ajax` function. However, there is redundancy in specifying both type and method properties with the same value ("POST").

The method property is an alias for the type property in the $.ajax function, so specifying both properties with the same value is unnecessary. You can remove either type or method from your code, and it will still work correctly. Here's an example:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "controller.php",
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "JSON",
});
```

or

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "controller.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "JSON",
});
```