# sending post with ajax - bad request issue

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post

Im just starting with API and I need a little bit of help...

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var json=`{
   "Teamname": "example",
   "Password": "example",
   "members": [{
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe",
    },
    {
        "name": "Kate",
        "surname": "Smith",

    },
    {
        "name": "Brad",
        "surname": "Warden",

    },
    {
        "name": "Antony",
        "surname": "McLeer",

    }
]
}`;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://52.233.158.172/change/api/en/account/register",
  data: "json",
  contetType: "application/json"
  });
  console.log(json);

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and I get for return bad request in console, I go through code several times and everything should just work fine but obviously something is missing

Also if i go with postman I get 200 OK response...can anybody help me what Am I missing?

Comment: You're sending `json` the string rather than the variable as you data parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are sending a string "json" in your post data when you need to send the variable json instead.

If you update your ajax request to:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://52.233.158.172/change/api/en/account/register",
    data: json,
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Note the removal of the quotes around json on line 4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get this from console : 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: {Errors: ["The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'."], Result: null} @karl

Comment: Based on the post linked below type can only be used in versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0. If you are using a version newer than that you may need to use method instead. I've update the post to show this change. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543174/what-is-the-diff-between-type-and-method-in-ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://52.233.158.172/change/api/en/account/register",
  data: "json",
  contetType: "application/json"
  });
```

should be

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://52.233.158.172/change/api/en/account/register",
  data: json,
  contentType: "application/json"
  });
```

Comment: `contetType` should be `contentType` too ;)

Comment: yeap typo...however i get this from console : 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: API doesn't expose method to allow POST calls. [Docs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.5)