# why my ajax request doesn't send the content in the req.body?

Tags: node.js, ajax, reactjs, authentication, passport.js

I ran into this strange issue, i have two forms built with react , one is for signup and other one is for login.
I'm making an ajax request passing the content of signup form to the express server, the body gets parsed and i get the content from req.body without any issue,
however when i do the same thing for a login form, my backend server receives no content like email and password, but if it is done with postman it works fine, 
below is the given code for making an api call with ajax from react

```
  login: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.refs.loginpassword.value);
    var userdata = {
        "email": this.refs.loginusername.value,
        "password": this.refs.loginpassword.value
    }
    console.log(userdata);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType:"application/json",
        datatype:"jsonp",
        Data: userdata,
        url: "http://localhost:5000/signin",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
},
```

if i log the userdata to the console i can see the fields are populated but they aren't received on backend, following is the code written on the backend express server

```
   app.post('/signin', function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.body);

    passport.authenticate('local-login',{
    successRedirect:'/profile',
    failureRedirect:'/failureredirect',
    failureFlash:true
})(req,res,next)}
```

this redirects to the route "/failureredirect" without hitting the login strategy upon inspection i found out that the body is blank, no content is received here, but if i request the very same route with postman the authentication process works very well, what is going wrong here.
Remember, i have configured body parsed well with the express server , hence it works well for signup but not for login .

Comment: Try changing `type: "POST"` to `method: "POST"`. Also, sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828554/sending-post-with-ajax-bad-request-issue/48828585#48828585

Comment: no luck with changing type:"POST" to method: "POST"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three problems:

You are passing jQuery an *object* not a string of JSON. It will encode it using standard form encoding methods.

Either remove the claim you are using JSON:

> ```
>    contentType:"application/json",
> ```

or use `JSON.stringify` to convert the object to JSON.

Which you choose will depend on your server-side body-parser settings.

---

> ```
>    datatype:"jsonp",
> ```

JavaScript is case-sensitive. The `dataType` property has a capital `T` in the middle of it.

JSONP, however, is incompatible with POST requests. This should *probably* be:

```
dataType: "json"
```

… but it depends on what kind of response your server-side code makes.

---

> ```
>    Data: userdata,
> ```

Again, JavaScript is case-sensitive. The property is called `data`, not `Data`.

Comment: thanks for in depth insight , I already got it fixed. how ever i ran into some other issue relevant to CORS, from my express server I want to redirect to another domain from which the request is initiated. I have configured cors permissions with server but it can not redirect to the route say no access controll allow origin header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score -1):

Sigh, the problem was with the ajax request , in ajax request the key data was written as Data which made it not work,

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/login",
        type: "POST",
        datatype:"JSON",
        Data: userdata,

        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
```

change the Data:userdata to data:userdata and it works. ajax requests are case sensitive.